# Is there a way to store a reference to a deep object key in a variable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, reference

Giving the following example:

```js
const a = {
  b: {
    c: null
  }
};

let d = ["b", "c"];

let reference = a;

d.forEach(key => (reference = reference[key]));

reference = "fe";

console.log("With a reference to the object deep key.");
console.log(a);

a["b"]["c"] = "fe";
console.log("Directly setting it, what I want.");
console.log(a);
```

Would it be possible to change the value of `c` with a reference to it? This is the closest I am but it obviously stores the `null` value on it.

Comment: `let ref = a.b; ref.c = 'fe';` is the best you can do. `ref = ...` never modifies an existing object.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is JavaScript a pass-by-reference or pass-by-value language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518000/is-javascript-a-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value-language)

Comment: Not directly. You can keep a reference one layer higher on `a['b']` for example, which is an Object and has a reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `pop` the last key from `d` and use it on `reference` at the end.

```js
let d = ["b", "c"],
    last = d.pop(),
    reference = a;

path.forEach(key => reference = reference[key] || {});

reference[last] = "fe";
```

You can use `reduce` to get the object's reference in the accumulator and update the `last` key with the provided value

```js
function updatePath(original, path, value) {
  const last = path.pop();
  path.reduce((acc, key) => acc[key] || {}, original)[last] = value;
  return original
}

const eg1 = {
  b: {
    c: null
  }
}

console.log(
  updatePath(eg1, ['b', 'c'], 'fe')
)

const eg2 = {
  1: {
    2: {
      3: 'initial'
    }
  }
}

console.log(
  updatePath(eg2, ['1', '2', '3'], 'updatedValue')
)
```

Comment: The more generic concept of a configurable setter/getter is called *functional lenses* or just *lenses* (plural, or *lens* singular). [Here is an article on them](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/lenses-b85976cb0534). [Ramda has an implementation](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#lens). [Lodash also has one](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#set) but doesn't call it a lens.

Answer (score 0):

You can only change values "by reference" for arrays and objects. But for objects and arrays, yes you can!

You can check [this post](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) that explains well the primitive values vs reference values.